# ReactNative send style as props to component

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new to learning `React Native` and I would like to build a (ReactNaive & Expo) application with a good interface look, How can I build a component and send `style{backgroundColor}` as props then render the component on Home

**home.js**

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import { View, Text , Image , ScrollView} from 'react-native';
    import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    import { COLORS, SIZES,FONTS} from '../styles/theme.js';
    import Category from '../components/Category.js';
    import CategorySlider from '../components/CategorySlider'
    
     const Home = () => {
         function renderHeader(){
             return(
            <View
             style = {{
            flexDirection: 'row' ,
            marginTop: 40,
            marginBottom: 10,
            paddingHorizontal:SIZES.padding,
            alignItems : 'center'
    
             }}
             >
             <View style={{flex:1}}>
              <Text >Hello , Wafa</Text>
             </View>
             {/* Nonfiction Button */}
         </View>
             )}
    
        return (
            <View 
            style ={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: COLORS.white
            }}
            >
                
                {/* HEADER */}
                {renderHeader()}
    
                {/* Content */}
               <View style={{height:130 , marginTop:SIZES.margin}}>
             <ScrollView 
              horizontal={true}
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              >
                <Category name='Balance'  />
                <Category name='Saving' style={COLORS.green} />
                <Category name='Income' style={ COLORS.brown } />
                <Category name='Loans' style={ COLORS.pink}/>
                <Category name='Saving' style={ COLORS.pink}/>
                <Category name='Saving' style={ COLORS.pink}/>
             </ScrollView>
               </View>
              
                <CategorySlider/>
            
            </View>
        )
    }
    
    export default Home;
```

It is the component I want to render on `home.js`

**Category.js**

```js
    import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
    import { Text, View ,StyleSheet ,Image } from 'react-native'
    import { backgroundColor } from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ReactNativeStyleAttributes';
    import { COLORS, SIZES,FONTS} from '../styles/theme.js';
    
    export default class Category extends PureComponent {
        render() {
            return (
                <View style={{marginLeft: SIZES.margin ,marginRight: SIZES.margin}}>
                    <View>
                 <View style={{ 
                 height: 60,
                 width: 60,
                 backgroundColor:COLORS.pink,
                 borderRadius: SIZES.radius,
                 }}>
                  <View />
                   <View>
                    <Image />
                   </View>
                 </View>
                 <Text 
                 style={{textAlign:'center'}}
                 >
                 {this.props.name}</Text>
               </View>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
```

l made also File for Design system contains style I will repeat on the application.

**theme.js:**

```js
    import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
    import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
    
    
    export const COLORS = {
        green: "#68AB9F",
        brown: "#c18e62",
        pink: "#d99e96" ,
        gray: "#383e42",
        white: "#f5f7fc",
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're working on one with a Functional based component **(home.js)** and one with Class-based **(Category.js)**. Standard is if first convert your `Category` component with functional then you can save that props to your `Category` component like:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Text, View ,StyleSheet ,Image } from 'react-native'
import { backgroundColor } from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ReactNativeStyleAttributes';
import { COLORS, SIZES,FONTS} from '../styles/theme.js';

const Category = (props) => {
      const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState(props.style || null);  //store your prop in state like this
      const [name, setName] = useState(props.name || null);

        return (
            <View style={{marginLeft: SIZES.margin ,marginRight: SIZES.margin}}>
                <View>
             <View style={{ 
             height: 60,
             width: 60,
             backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
             borderRadius: SIZES.radius,
             }}>
              <View />
               <View>
                <Image />
               </View>
             </View>
             <Text 
             style={{textAlign:'center'}}
             >
             {name}</Text>
           </View>
            </View>
        )
}

export default Category;
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: can you check in which line?

Comment: just updated the answer. now check

Comment: also there is another issue , what you think about change the Class Component to Function Component

Comment: yeah, it would be good because home.js is already a functional component.

Comment: I just converted it, updated the answer

Comment: sorry, replaced comma with semicolon while setting the state in `useState`. updated again

Comment: your solution effect all props on the component \{{this.props.name}}

Comment: I didn't get it, can you show the screenshot

Comment: isuee {TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.name')}

Comment: there is no `this.props.name` in my answer for **Category.js**, you need to update your code like mine

Comment: that work thank you ,it so helpful

Answer (score 0):

In your parent component take your style object in the wrapper of child component i.e.

```
function Parent(){
   return (
      <Child cssdata={{backgroundColor:'red',marginLeft:8}}/>
   )
}
```

and in your child component take this data from props and applied to it

```
function Child(props){
   return (
     <View style={props.cssdata}></View>
   )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: can you more explain it is not clear

Comment: I mean in your Category component pass your css design inside an object like this 

<Category cssdata={backgroundColor:'Colors.GREEN'}/>

and inside the Category.js file  it will be call through props  like this 

<View style={props.cssdata}/> 

And sorry for bracket mismatch in above answer